# Compare serial input to perform action

Tags: vb.net, arduino, serial-port

I believe this should be VERY simple, but have racked my brain as to why it is not working.  I am using an Arduino to send an "O" and a "C" to the serial port. I want to perform a sub when "O" is sent, and another sub when "C" is sent.  I can confirm that "O" and "C" are being sent, and are strings by using this:

```css
    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Dim data As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
        MessageBox.Show(data)
        MessageBox.Show(data.GetType.ToString)
    End Sub
```

I expected to be able to take that string and run the subroutine I wanted, based on whether data = "O" or "C".  but I am not able to do this at all.. I can not get this to work (the problem is something with the select-case statement):

```html
    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Dim data As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
        Select Case data
            Case "O"
                open()
            Case "C"
                close()
        End Select
    End Sub
```

I am not understanding why the simple string comparison is not working.  Thank You for any help with this.

Comment: Check to see if `data` consists of more than a single character. If it has a trailing blank or an unprintable character, you wouldn't notice it when you display it in the `MessageBox` in your test case.

Comment: Ok.  I did not think to do that.  I added a stop at the end of this Sub, and watched the locals.  it had "O" & vbCr for data.  I have to learn what & vbCr means now, but I did this to my code and now it works.

Comment: Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        Dim data As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
        Select Case data
            Case "O" & vbCr
                open()
            Case "C" & vbCr
                close()
        End Select
    End Sub

Comment: I cant find how to insert code into this comment, correctly.. Also, I thought I  was supposed to accept your comment as an answer, but I do not see any way to do so.  I hate to not give you credit... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`vbCr` is the "carriage return" character that indicates the end of the line. If you know there is always one character before the vbCr, you can use the [SubString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) method to have your `Select Case` check only that character.

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim data As String = SerialPort1.ReadLine()
    Select Case data.SubString(0, 1)
        Case "O"
            open()
        Case "C"
            close()
    End Select
End Sub
```

If the data that is returned is not guaranteed to be one character (plus vbCr), you will need more code, but the code you would need depends on what the possible values are.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just sending one character to the serial host from the Arduino, send it with `Serial.print('C')` instead of `Serial.println('C')`. That way, the Arduino will only send the character you want to look at, and omit the two new line bytes.